# Incorrect initialization of a structure instance with data from const char *[][]

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, struct, constants

I obtained the following compilation error:

> error: initializer element is not constant

while using this code (divided into 3 files, as follows):

**File 1**

This array is used to easily switch between language versions of menu.

```
#define LANG_EN 0
#define LANG_PL 1
#define LANGUAGES 2
const char *const message[][LANGUAGES] = {


#define MSG_INTRO 0
     /*0*/  { "Hello", "Witamy" },


#define MSG_MENU1 1
     /*1*/  { "Option1", "Opcja1" },


#define MSG_MENU2 2
     /*2*/  { "Option2", "Opcja2" },
};
```

**File 2**

This file contains,among others, the definition of the structure used:

```
struct _menuitem
{
    const char *const text;
    int action;
};

struct _menuitem const menu;
```

**File 3**

In main.c I initialize the structure:

```
#define PGM_STR(X) ((const  char[]) { X })

const struct _menuitem const menu = {PGM_STR(message[MSG_INTRO][LANG_PL]),  0};
```

---

When I put any string in quotes (like "Testest") under `PGM_STR` macro then everything is fine.

**Q:** How should I initialize the struct with string data from the

```
const char *const message[][LANGUAGES]
```

so that it remains inline as shown above?

What am I doing wrong?

*I know there are a lot of topics concerning this compilation error, but none of them actually concerns this type of array-structure combination.*